# Dplyr and RJDBC : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbGetQuery’ for signature ‘"JDBCConnection", "tbl_df"

Tags: r, parallel-processing, dplyr, rjdbc, multidplyr

I'm using  RJDBC package for connecting to an Oracle DB. 
I need to retrieve a huge amount of data, and I would like to distribute the inquiry through different cores. 
I know that the table has five millions records. Thus I write a SQL Query like:

```
SqlCMD =   "SELECT * from ( SELECT m.*, rownum r FROM  Table ) WHERE r >= minV AND r < maxV"

points = ceiling(seq(1, rownum, length.out = 20))

 [1]       1  269578  539154  808730 1078306 1347882 1617458 1887034 2156610 2426186 2695762 2965338 3234914 3504490 3774066
[16] 4043642 4313218 4582794 4852370 5121946

sqlCl = NULL
for (i in 1:19){
  sqlCl[i] = gsub("minV", points[i], sqlCMD)
  sqlCl[i] = gsub("maxV", points[i+1], sqlCl[i])
}
sqlCl = sqlCl %>% as.data.frame

group <- rep(1:cl, length.out = 19)
sqlCl <- bind_cols(tibble(group),  sqlCl)
cl <- create_cluster(8)
```

Then I distribute to cores and I set env cores

```
by_group <- sqlCl %>%
  partition(group, cluster = cl)

by_group %>%
  cluster_library("RJDBC") %>%
  cluster_library("dplyr") %>%
  cluster_assign_value("sqlCl", sqlCl) %>%
  cluster_assign_value("pathOjdbc", pathOjdbc)%>% #path to ojdbc8.jar
  cluster_assign_value("dbName", dbName) %>%
  cluster_assign_value("user", user)%>%
  cluster_assign_value("password", password) %>% 
  cluster_assign_value("dbGetQuery", dbGetQuery)


by_group %>%
  cluster_assign_value("conn", 
dbConnect(JDBC(driverClass="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", classPath = pathOjdbc), 
dbName, user , password))
```

Then I try to do the inquiry:

```
ws3_processed_in_parallel <- 
  by_group %>% 
  do({
    df = RJDBC::dbGetQuery(conn, sqlCl)
  })
```

I got this error and I really do not know what i can do.

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
  8 nodes produced errors; first error: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbGetQuery’ for signature ‘"JDBCConnection", "tbl_df"’
```

I'm trying also with "tbl" but I get this:

```
  Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
      unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbBegin’ for signature ‘"JDBCConnection"’
```

Answer (score 0):

`dbGetQuery` expects its `statement` argument to be of class `character`, whereas you seem to be using the whole thing that you have from `cluster_assign_value("sqlCl", sqlCl)`.
You are also using `cl` in creating `group` and `sqlCl` and I am not sure what `sqlCl` looks like in the end.

Maybe you want to use `cluster_assign_each(...` instead of `cluster_assign_value("sqlCl", sqlCl)`.

I am also not sure why you have `by_group %>% cluster_library(...` and not `cl %>% cluster_library(...`.